# Are there any examples of a Python PyGTK Pango editor toolbar?

Tags: python, pygtk, pango

I am looking for an example application written in Python and PyGTK.

There should be an editor out there somewhere that already does this.

Some app with a text editor row of buttons:
- Font
- Bold/italic/underline
- etc

I am hoping to avoid reinventing the wheel on this one! 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some related examples: KeepNote, which has a custom rich edit, and Rednotebook which implements KeepNote's richedit.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find any pygtk programs that do what you want, but here is a good tutorial to using pango: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pygtktutorial/pango/